# You tube plugin for html not working

Tags: html, youtube

I am using following code for plugin youtube video in HTML.

```
  <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=451l9lenoOs&hd=1"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=451l9lenoOs&hd=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

please help me find out solution .

Answer (score 1):

Use iframe instead embed(old) tag.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/451l9lenoOs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

copy from here(share -> source code):

[image]

Comment: @BadgujarBhushankumar If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :D http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png